# Compact Framework and JIT. How long could it take

Tags: performance, compact-framework, jit

We have/had a phantom delay in our app. This was traced to the initialisation of a singleton when the object was touched for the first time and was blamed on JIT. I'm not utterly convinced by this as there is no mechanism for measuring JIT (or is there?) and the entire delay was seven seconds. Seven seconds of JIT?!? Could that be forreal?

Either way I have difficulty in blaming things that one cannot easily measure. When I had a glance at the issue a while back I commented out a bunch of code and watched the seven second delay "jump" elsewhere in the app. Suggesting it is somehow happening on a background process somewhere (and I guess this would count JIT in as a potential cause).

Just for fun if there was a static object that happened to reference a lot of other objects does anyone have a rule of thumb for how long the JIT might take? Does anyone have further references so I can understand more about the JIT so I stand a chance of learning whether or not JIT is/was to blame for this slow down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only seen JIT take a really long time (greater than 1 second) in a weird bug that had to do with templated items inside a templated collection (see edit below).

At any rate, the fact you see it "move" definitely indicates to me that it probably isn't the issue.  To try to determine this definitively I'd look at using RPM to see what's happening right before and after the delay.

Expected JIT time is a really nebulous thing, since there are so many factors that can affect it.  Processor speed is an obvious one, but less obvious might be things like app storage media and device memory pressure.

Storage media can affect JIT speed because the JITter has to pull the IL from the media when it needs to JIT it, and if pulling it is slow, then JITting it will be slow.

Memory pressure is a tough one, and can have serious repercussions on a CE device.  The issue here is that when you start running out of memory, the EE will start pitching JITted code during collection - everything but the call stack.  Now if you're in a routine that, for example, calls out to some worker or helper stuff, or has a thread running, then that helper method could be getting pitched, JITted, pitched JITted, etc.  This is referred to as "thrash."

Identifying the latter is fairly easy with RPM (fixing it may not be so easy).  Look at the amount of code pitched to raise frequently and look for a strong correlation between a rise in the number of pitches and your perceived lock ups.

**Edit:** I finally found [the bug description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/150261e9-4be2-4675-842e-fbde0448e25c/).

Comment: Thanks for that bug description. v.Interesting and kinda funny too.

Answer (score 1):

JIT (and GC) timers etc. can be found here:

Performance Counters in the .NET Compact Framework
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172525.aspx)

Monitoring Application Performance on the .NET Compact Framework Part I - Enabling performance counters (http://blogs.msdn.com/davidklinems/archive/2005/10/04/476988.aspx)

Analyzing Device Application Performance with the .Net Compact Framework Remote Performance Monitor (http://blogs.msdn.com/stevenpr/archive/2006/04/17/577636.aspx)

Performance Counters in the .NET Framework
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8f5kw2e(VS.80).aspx)

Regards,
tamberg